# How to find the latest artifact version with Artifactory Query Language?

Tags: maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Until now, I used the Artifactory REST API to determine the last version (last snapshot) of a maven artifact with `groupId` and `artifactIid`:

```
/api/search/latestVersion?g={groupid}&a={artifactid}
```

This gives me exactly a string with the highest/last available (snapshot) version of this artifact.

However, this is sometimes really slow and one recommendation was to use the Artifactory Query Language (AQL).

Unfortunately I have not yet been able to find out how to map this functionality in AQL.

Could someone give me a clue as to what a corresponding query in AQL could look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

You can use AQL's SORT and LIMIT to retrieve your latest artifact, for example:

```
items.find(
{
            "repo":"my-repo"
    }
).sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(1)
```

You can find more examples [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-Sorting).

I would also recommend trying out the [Jfrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory), which also supports Sorting, and might be easier to use.

Comment: But what is with the limitation to groupid/artifactid? How to translate that into the fields provided by AQL?

Comment: you can use the "name" field with "$match" and incorparate wildcards in your query, for example: 
items.find(
{
                      "name":{"$match":"*somename-1.1.1.*"}
    }
).sort({"$desc" : ["name"]}).limit(1)

Comment: items.find(
{
                      "name":{"$match":"somename-1.1.1.*"}
    }
).sort({"$desc" : ["name"]}).limit(1)