# Artifactory REST API call to retrieve the latest artifact version for multiple artifacts

Tags: devops, artifactory, aql, jfrog-cli

This [blog](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-find-the-latest-artifact-version-based-on-layout/) describes how to fetch latest version for an artifact by repo layout and name. Is there any AQL/REST API call to achive the same for multiple artifacts at once.

My use case is get latest version for a list of artifacts. It can be achieved using sending multiple calls. Looking for efficient way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Artifactory REST API which supports getting the latest version for multiple artifacts.
AQL does not have a built in support for getting the latest version. You can try to achieve it by sorting the results, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742074/how-to-find-the-latest-artifact-version-with-artifactory-query-language), and do some post processing of the results to pick the latest version.
I think the best option would be performin multiple API calls.